# Straight double quotes on Bluetooth keyboard

Tags: macos, keyboard, keybindings

[image: Bluetooth keyboard]

I purchased a Bluetooth keyboard yesterday for my MacBook Pro Late 2013 (macOS Mojave 10.14.6) and I am having problems with this (") character. I cannot find it on the keyboard.

Is there a chance to remap another key to type that? Or maybe add some combinations like <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd><</kbd>?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which key does what depends on the Input Source you are using (not your hardware). These are activated  in System Preferences/Keyboard/Input Sources.  To see the current mappıng, use [Keyboard Viewer](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-the-keyboard-viewer-on-mac-mchlp1015/10.14/mac/10.14).

Your keyboard is Turkish Qwerty PC.  If you [make that your Input Source](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/type-language-mac-input-sources-mchlp1406/10.14/mac/10.14) in System Preferences, then double quote ıs on Control i as you mentıoned.  (Using Control for special characters is very unusual on a Mac, normally it would only be Option and Option plus Shift).

If you want to change that, it is quite easy to make a custom layout using [Ukelele](https://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele).  I can help if you are having problems with it.

Comment: yes, Feels like option. It types a single quote with a underline(which disappears). Maybe @lutfitekin is typing it twice.

Answer (score -2):

At the end I triggered the virtual keyboard and figured out that typing <kbd>Ctrl-i</kbd> will result in a `"`.